# Record Type Reverser

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

I'd like to reverse the property names and types for a record that has unique constant property values.

```
const VALUE = {
    field1: "fieldA",
    field2: "fieldB"
} as const

type Reversed = Reverser<typeof VALUE>

//which should yield the following type
type Reversed = {
    fieldA: "field1";
    fieldB: "field2";
}
```

I dont think it is possible due to the fact that the property values arent necessarily unique. But I ask anyways ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a mapped type with an `as` clause:

```
type Reverser<T extends Record<PropertyKey, PropertyKey>> = {
  [P in keyof T as T[P]]: P
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAagQQDIFUCiMC8MDeAoGQmAMwEsBTAGwBMBGALhgCIyrqEmAaAo1mgJkYsKNAEJM8AXxgBDCDFCQoePFACeAB3IwASuQBu5AE4RjAHgAqMcgA8o5MNXl7QR6mYAKRkFqPqA0uRqnDBePsYBQQB8UVi4PADaHjCkYDAA1kEgxDBWcrlJALqFjB5SKupaugbGptRxeoYm5pXk2fDI6FEqAPQ9MK3VTXVx+H1EhHzsQlO0TADceOMTU6IzItT8C0v90kA)

The `as` clause will take the `P` key and map it to anything else. In this case we map it to the type of the property at the key `P` (`T[P]`) . For the value of the property we just use the `P` as the type.

Comment: Cool. Seems like the `extends` clause made the difference

Comment: @robkuz Yup. `as` makes a lot of things easier. We could probably have come up with a solution without it. But it would have been ugly.