# How to build a Unique Record Type Reverser

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

I want to build a type from type reverser as explained here
[Record Type Reverser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70037753/record-type-reverser)

```
const VALUE = {
    field1: "fieldA",
    field2: "fieldB",
    field3: "fieldC"
} as const

type UReversed = UniqueReverser<typeof VALUE>
/*
should yield 
{
        fieldA: "field1"
        fieldB: "field2"
        fieldC: "field3"
}
*/
```

However this should **only** work if all literal values are unique!

Given the code below

```
const VALUE = {
    field1: "fieldA",
    field2: "fieldB",
    field3: "fieldA" // "fieldA" as a duplicate value here
} as const

type UReversed = UniqueReverser<typeof VALUE>
// should yield never
```

I want the type definition to yield yield`never`

Probably this could help
[Ensure the Uniqueness of Literal Values in a Record Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70037967/ensure-the-uniqueness-of-literal-values-in-a-record-type)

Comment: Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/W4yxOw)?  You could just use the answers given to you for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70037753/record-type-reverser and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70037967/ensure-the-uniqueness-of-literal-values-in-a-record-type together.  If I go ahead an answer this one, it's going to be nearly word-for-word the same as my existing one, except that I'd also be copying @TitianCernicova-Dragomir's answer.  I'm kind of stumped about how one should proceed here.

Comment: @jcalz No worries about taking it :). Yeah. You can just put those together basically

Comment: @jcalz yeah that was what I was looking for. Please do answer it. I found your last explanation extremely helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70038857/2887218) I explain how to detect if an object type has duplicate property value types (subject to caveats about optional properties, index signatures, unions, intersections, subtypes, and other complications).  I won't duplicate this part of the answer here.

Anyway, one could change that solution a little to make something more general:

```
type IfUniqueProperties<T, Y = T, N = never> = unknown extends {
   [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends Omit<T, K>[Exclude<keyof T, K>] ? unknown : never
}[keyof T] ? N : Y
```

Here, `IfUniqueProperties<T, Y, N>` checks `T` to see if its properties are all unique; if so, it returns `Y`: if not, it returns `N`.  All I did was change the `never` in the other solution to the generic `N`, and the `T[keyof T]` to the generic `Y`.  I also made `N` default to `never` and `Y` default to `T`, since this is often what people want with these sort of "check" types.  Let's make sure it works:

```
type U = IfUniqueProperties<{a: 1, b: 2}, "unique", "duplicates">
// type U = "unique"

type D = IfUniqueProperties<{a: 1, b: 1}, "unique", "duplicates">
// type D = "duplicates"
```

So we can write `RecToDU<T>` from the other answer in terms of `IfUniqueProperties`:

```
type RecToDU<T> = IfUniqueProperties<T, T[keyof T]>;
type ZY = RecToDU<{ a: "z", b: "y" }> // "z" | "y"
type NV = RecToDU<{ a: "z", b: "z" }> // never
```

We do want `never` so I left `N` as the default, but for `Y` you want `T[keyof T]` instead of `T`.  So `IfUniqueProperties` is a generalized version of `RecToDU`.

---

Therefore, to answer *this* question, we can take the `Reverser<T>` type from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70037795/2887218) and write `UniqueReverser<T>` as follows:

```
type UniqueReverser<T extends Record<keyof T, PropertyKey>> =
   IfUniqueProperties<T, Reverser<T>>;
```

Let's test it:

```
const VALUES = {
   field1: "fieldA",
   field2: "fieldB",
   field3: "fieldC"
} as const

type UReversed = UniqueReverser<typeof VALUES>
/* type UReversed = {
 readonly fieldA: "field1";
 readonly fieldB: "field2";
 readonly fieldC: "field3"; */
```

and:

```
const VALUES = {
   field1: "fieldA",
   field2: "fieldB",
   field3: "fieldA"
} as const

type UReversed = UniqueReverser<typeof VALUES>
// type UReversed = never
```

Looks like what you wanted.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgZgVQHYEsCOBXCAFATge0l2BQgGcAeAFQBooBNKAXilqgDlmokIA3CXAD4uGJAGsk+AO5IoEAB7AISACZkoAbwBQUXQG0A0lBSyxEEPjisAugFoA-AC5Wh63MXK1UAPIBbFMDUdAaCegCi8gDGADYYKhAUZhZWbCFu9lCiEtKyzjz8uFoAvnpJljZQGZzO9FpaoJBQCFzwyOhYeIQCJOQUGlAAhs4AjHQARs4ATFBFdABEou0Qc-MqGGDRKJEDSmRzgloA9IdQDdDNLAuomMt1Z1AAIi2I1x0ERD2U-UNQo1ATvxm80WNxWUDmaw2Wx25H2RxO9yel0hm22uzmd3A0AAShBIlR8A8ENRhCxWq8cO9uqRKGwqKVzOUqNZBABuepYqAALUYLFx+MJxO+zjmAC8wQC5iA5jNhMdweKoAAfcHSjmNdgANS4-IJRL6gxF4vGRplRTlJ3yAjqNvVOL4AjIAmo7iUqnU-PwuBUFE6HxABnMdD93QD5kEpM0On02GMpkZKUG6np2Gs1mc2GKmMabRuuIKTtwLoUbq8nu9iQTrGDVOIYZAEeY0dgLyWIeINKCUHzjudVAj7K0SAGvnIYAGkWgAA0o7ooJF8EgyMAoJqAIIAGQQYQAylxtHO53BSNEVMMRceIKe1ytm0eTypJheHwAhW+H3SX08AZmfV5UADCGJzkUSbzouy51HO9wID2uBOioXC5lgcGFhQZzlOuW67gcc6HAAVKcnKwQ68EQIhLAHnOuAQAMKiLtEIBQF+Khrn+p7DHM7KHjRdEMUxLEvuxj5cXevH0UgjHMQ+AHCd+XFQPhhxZkOI5jhO0CMFR4FLiuWHbnulF3p+D7nuCLE3jQxnSf+T7ma+74fixv72f+N7NqBAzqAuulQboMGoeRSEUoFRYYVY+k4c28oBaRCFcFahRFEAA)